# Batch file - loop through csv and create path variable from two columns

Tags: variables, batch-file, csv

I want to loop through a CSV file and create a full path variable out of two columns - and only if one specific column has the value "Folder".

This actually works right now, but the not working part is the creation of the path variable.

two points:

the two columns I look at are the deepest folder and the root folders aboth. Like this:
first/first1/ + second = first/first1/second

So, the deepest folder will always be filled and I can just take it like it comes.

The folders above will either be filled or it will be a 0 standing in the column.
Also the string will have a "**/**" which I have to CUT and replace with a backslash ..

Here's my code:

```
For /F "tokens=1-7 delims=;" %%a in (L:/Mappe1.csv) Do (

if "%%b"=="Folder" (
   set folder=%%c
   if NOT %%f==0 (
      set rootFolder ==f
      rem check for slash..
      if %rootFolder=~-1%==/ (
          rem cut it out
          SET rootFolder=%rootFolder:~0,-1%
      )
      rem both variables set
      set finalPath=%rootFolder%%folder%
   ) else (
      rem just the folder
      set finalpath=%folder%
   )
echo %finalpath%
)
)
```

**Sampe of the CSV:**

ID;PROGID;NAME; PARENTID; PARENT_FOLDER;PATH; ISNTANCE; DESC; ORDER;
23;Folder;Stammordner;4;4;PRODUKTION/;0;;;

**What's not working:**

- right now I get the "Echo is off" output everytime I run. I think that somehow the finalpath is not set, but I don't get where.
- also I don't know if the way I do it is the common way - I'm so much new to batch - even if I'm a developer its somehow very complicated for me ..

Regards

Comment: If you provide a sample of the `csv` file and `describe the task` then we may find a more straight forward way to do it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer.. I thought that I have a syntax error thats why I didn't provide a sample. I edit the main post with a sample and the for loop which I use

Comment: Your code has errors: at the moment you are checking the 6th token and if it is not "0" you are setting a variable to "token6/token2" otherwise set the variable to "token2" alone.  Is that it?  is the folder delimiter really / or \ ?

Comment: The 7th token can either be the path or 0, if it is NOT 0 then its the path and I assign it to the variable. Yes thats it.. where is the error? I don't see it :/

I tried it with / and it didn't work - with \ it worked so I think its \.. thats why i change the / in the paths with \

Comment: `set rootFolder ==f` is a syntax error.  You also need to use delayed expansion to change a variable within a loop, and use !variable! syntax.

Comment: `%rootFolder%=~-1%` should be `%rootFolder:~-1%` too, and the two terms need to be enclosed in double quotes to protect against spaces and & chracters etc

Comment: Oh damn, I'm sorry, I couldn't copy the code because it's on a different pc with no internet, so I typed everything. The actual code is: set rootFolder=%%f .. but I will try it with the delayed expansion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should be functionally the same, given the sample data, and the fact that the 6th token only has a single slash.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
For /F "tokens=1-7 delims=;" %%a in (L:\Mappe1.csv) Do (
   if "%%b"=="Folder" (
      set "finalpath=%%c"
      if NOT "%%f"=="0" set "finalpath=%%f%%c"
   )
set "finalpath=!finalpath:/=!"
echo "!finalpath!"
)
pause
```

Comment: Your code is working like a charm. Thanks for that. I'll mark your answer but I have another question at this point: what is this line doing? set "finalpath=!finalpath:/=!" you are replacing every slash with nothing right? How can I replace every slash with a backslash at this point?

Comment: `set "finalpath=!finalpath:/=\!"` <--- this will replace forward slashes with backslashes.  And yes, I was replacing every forward slash with nothing, as the example just had one slash.

Comment: Perfect, I undestand now much more how the syntax works. Thank you very much!

Comment: Hey, its me again.. I have one problem now. My CSV sometimes has empty columns, so its displayed like this ;;text;0;;1;.
Now, if I ask for token %%f it skips empty columns and graps the next column with text in it. Sometimes it is a 0. 

The problem is now that the code above with the 0 check doesn't work at this point.. any idea? I tried to replace every 0 with an emptystring - but sometimes I have a string with a foldername with a 0 in it so this will not do it...

Comment: Can you zip up some sample CSV files and put them on dropbox?  It would help to see the actual data and see if there is a pattern than can be used.

Comment: I found a way to edit the source system where the CSV come from - I can edit the code and kick out the 0 - because it's only filled if there is no path above.. also I can handle that there never will be an empty column - that would make everything much more easy..